# SQL Application Username & Password Check

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm working on an application which I intend on protecting with Usernames & Passwords stored on a MS SQL Server. I've been trying for a number of days to get Visual Basics to compare the text entered in the two text boxes with the Username and Password on the SQL Database but I can't figure out a way to do it. The connection to the databse is already established and I'm able to manipulate the data on the Server from my Application, but I just can't figure out the code for 'comparing' the credentials.

The database that I'm connecting to is called `Members_Details` and the Table is called `Logins`. The logins table only holds two columns `Name` & `Passkey` (Username & Password.)

What I've tried so far is this:

```
  SQL = "Select * from logins " & _
          "where Name like '%" & Me.Usernametxt.Text.Trim & "%' AND Passkey LIKE Me.Passwordtxt.Text.Trim & "%'"
```

But I don't know where to go after that :/

Any help would be appreciated, and please not security is not an issue at the moment.

Comment: Also note that Visual Studio was doing its best to help you find this one by the way it had coloured your line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the embedding of the Passwordtxt textbox value inside the sql text.

```
SQL = "Select * from logins " & _
      "where Name like '%" & Me.Usernametxt.Text.Trim & _
      "%' AND Passkey LIKE '" & Me.Passwordtxt.Text.Trim  & "'"
```

However, also if you don't want advice on security, do a little step forward and write

```
SQL = "Select * from logins " & _
      "where Name like @uname " & _
      "AND Passkey = @pass"

Dim sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(SQL, con)
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", "%" & Me.Usernametxt.Text.Trim & "%")
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", Me.Passwordtxt.Text.Trim )
Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
  if reader.HasRows Then
     ' user authenticated
```

Also, *usually*, the passwords are required to be typed exactly (case sensitive) and thus not retrieved using a LIKE operator and wildcards.
The wildcard is also a bit strange for the username while it is acceptable to use the LIKE operator to allow the username to be case insensitive